# Should it be "If I were" or "If I was"?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct?
"If I were a flower I would bloom"
Or should it be "if I was"?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

Answer (score 0):

The rule is, if your hypothetical scenario suggests your being something you're not (or something that isn't true), use were:

> If I were stronger, I'd break your arm!

(I'm not stronger.)

> If I were a flower, I'd go crazy!

(I'm not really a flower, though I've been called a pansy.)

> If my room were clean, it would be a first.

(My room isn't clean.)

If it may be true, use was:

> Is this answer was poorly constructed, it may have been due to the fact that I was really tired.

(It may be poorly written.)

The same rules apply to sentences with *though*:

> He appears as though he were homeless.

(He's not homeless, yet.)

This is addressed, among other places, on pages 56-57 of my favorite reference book, "Woe Is I" by Patricia O' Conner.

Also supporting this explanation is rule 10 on [subject/verb agreement at grammarbook.com](http://m.grammarbook.com/grammar-rules/subject-and-verb-agreement.aspx).

Alternate views I hadn't known of before, like [this](http://m.grammarbook.com/grammar-rules/subject-and-verb-agreement.aspx), can be found but in my humble, unbiased opinion, the acceptance of *was* in place of *were* in false hypotheticals is limited to a colloquial environment, which encompasses an ever broadening scope of society. I could well be mistaken (I was once before), but I've seen no evidence of such. (Even the cited page still recommends the use of *were* in untrue "if" clauses.)

Comment: I know what you mean, but I think we should add that the less formal _If I was a flower_ would also be possible and grammatically correct. This "was" has nothing to with past time; rather it is concerned with modality, a kind of meaning involving non-factuality, and hence is best referred to as a 'modal preterite'.

Comment: @BillJ thanks for the input; according to the resources I have at my disposal, my position is accurate. As far as I'm aware, "If I was a flower..." doesn't work. If you know otherwise, perhaps an explanation with resources would be good to add here as well. See rule 10 at http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp

Comment: Hi Kai. Here's a link to a website in which one of the world's leading grammarians, Geoffrey Pullum, notes that _If I was_ and _If I were_ mean the same thing: [link](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/if-i-was-vs-if-i-were/). Many people prefer "were", but most grammarians say "was" is also correct.